# auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword - Firebase authentication using the latest version - 20.0.2 is giving error

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, mobile-application

With the firebase version-19.2.0 , authentication works fine.

On using firebase(20.0.2 version) authentication,
`auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener { task->`
following error is shown.

`com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ socket failed:EPERM (Operation not permitted) ] at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztt.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:4) at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzvb.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:9) at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzvc.zzk(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:1) at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzuz.zzh(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:25) at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztq.zzk(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:1) at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzoi.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:2) at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzvg.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:26) at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzuq.zzf(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:4) at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzpy.zzj(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:5) at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztu.zzi(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:8) at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzsk.zzd(Unknown Source:15) at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzsj.accept(Unknown Source:6) at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zacj.doExecute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:2) at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaf.zac(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:6) at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zac(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:167) at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zab(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:139) at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zabg(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:99) at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zabe(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:40) at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.onConnected(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:19) at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zaf.onConnected(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:2) at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzg.zzj(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.0:24) at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zza.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.0:12) at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzb.zzo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.0:11) at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzc.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.0:49) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) at com.google.android.gms.internal.common.zzi.dispatchMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.0:8) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67) 2021`

Answer (score 1):

Go to proguard-rules.pro file and add this line:

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *; }
```